# How to copy and paste from a variable in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, copy, paste, sendkeys, powershell-cmdlet

I'm trying to look up a value in PowerShell and paste it as a string into a line of text on another application.

In this instance I need to put the date into a line for an API call. I've found the date and can access the line where I need to input the date. I'm having trouble highlighting the date output, or using the variable where I have stored the date to paste that date into the line of code I'm using.

## PowerShell code

```
$TDay = (Get-date).AddDays(-14)
Get-Date $TDay -Format MM-dd-yyyy
```

--API call

```
https:\\companyteam.teamwork.com/desk/v1/tickets/search.json?lastUpdated=07/26/2019
```

I'm able to delete the previous date but now I need to paste the value of the result from the PowerShell Script into where the date is displayed on the API call.

To solve my problem I think I'll need to manually highlight the results from the API call using the PowerShell mouse commands or if I could potentially just tell PowerShell to paste the result of Get-Date $TDay -Format MM-dd-yyyy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Set-Clipboard` to set the clipboard contents, which is the equivalent to a copy. You can use `Get-Clipboard` to paste copied contents to the console or as a variable value. You can also just paste from any copy-paste menu that has access to your clipboard.

```
Get-Date $TDay -Format MM-dd-yyyy | Set-Clipboard

$variable = Get-Clipboard
```

Since I am not sure how you are making the API call, simplistically speaking let's assume the URI is just a string. You can still use the `Get-Clipboard` command or variable within the sub-expression operator `$()`. Variables don't technically need the sub-expression unless you are accessing properties of that variable.

```
"https:\\companyteam.teamwork.com/desk/v1/tickets/search.json?lastUpdated=$(Get-Clipboard)"

# OR 

"https:\\companyteam.teamwork.com/desk/v1/tickets/search.json?lastUpdated=$variable"
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice involving the clipboard. I was having trouble using it. How would I then paste the contents of the $variable onto the end of the API call?

Comment: You can use the sub-expression operator $() within a string: `$(Get-Clipboard)` or just `$variable`.

Comment: I have to do the paste within the API program itself so the $(Get-Clipboard) answer doesn't take but you've given me a good increase in knowledge and I have a better path to take. Thank you very much